# How to declare DTD elements?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm working on an assignment and got my result, however it seemed I forgot to declare the elements in my DTD file. Do I declare all elements or just elements with extra information in it? If I'm not clear, here's an extract from my assignment:

```
<entry id= 'c01'>
<MetaTags>Business</MetaTags>   
<title><brand>HP Pavilion</brand><name>550-112NA</name></title>
<Desciption>While other towers have been standing still, HP has revolutionized the category. From magnified performance and reliability, to its stylish redesign, this HP Pavilion is the best thing to happen to towers in over 20 years.</Desciption>
<Price>€579</Price>
<Image src ="Image1.jpg"/>
<Specs>
    <CPU>A10-8750 APU</CPU>
    <GPU>Radeon R7</GPU>
    <RAM>8 GB DDR3</RAM>
    <Storage><HDD> 2TB </HDD><SSD></SSD></Storage>
    <OS>Windows 10</OS>
    <optional>
        <Monitor>LG 22" Full HD TV</Monitor>
        <Keyboard>Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600</Keyboard>
        <Mouse>Logitech M705 Mouse</Mouse>              
        </optional>
    </Specs>
</entry>
```

Would the tag entry have to be declared, however no other elements would because they don't have additional variables?

If that's correct, would the declaration look like this:

```
 <!ATTLIST entry id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

I hope I'm making my question clear, as I'm new to XML.Here's my DTD if you need to see that, and if I'm doing anything else wrong. Thanks!

```
<!ELEMENT ComputerShop (entry+)>
<!ELEMENT entry (MetaTags, title, Description, Price, Image, Specs)>
<!ELEMENT MetaTags (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Image (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (brand, name)>
<!ELEMENT brand (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Specs (CPU, GPU, RAM, Storage, OS, optional)>
<!ELEMENT CPU (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT GPU (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT RAM (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Storage (HDD | SSD)>
<!ELEMENT OS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT optional (Monitor | Keyboard | Mouse>
<!ELEMENT Monitor (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Keyboard (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Mouse (#PCDATA)>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I forgot to declare the elements in my DTD file

I think you mean "I forgot to declare the attributes in my DTD file".

Any attributes (the "extra information" on the elements) must be declared.

So you need to declare the `id` attribute on the `entry` element and the `src` attribute on the `Image` element.

Here are additional changes that you need to make...

**DTD Changes**

- Missing closing paren in `<!ELEMENT Specs (CPU, GPU, RAM, Storage, OS, optional)>`
- Declare HDD and SSD elements: `<!ELEMENT HDD (#PCDATA)>` and `<!ELEMENT SDD (#PCDATA)>`
- Declaration of `optional` needs to change. Maybe to `<!ELEMENT optional (Monitor | Keyboard | Mouse)*>` (zero or more occurrences of Monitor, Keyboard, or Mouse (in any order)) or to `<!ELEMENT optional (Monitor?, Keyboard?, Mouse?)>` (zero or one Monitor followed by zero or one Keyboard followed by zero or one Mouse).

**XML Changes**

- `Description` misspelled as `Desciption`.
- Content of `Storage` is one `HDD` or one `SSD`; not both. Remove the empty `<SSD></SSD>`.

Here are the corrected files...

**DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT ComputerShop (entry+)>
<!ELEMENT entry (MetaTags, title, Description, Price, Image, Specs)>
<!ATTLIST entry id CDATA #REQUIRED> 
<!ELEMENT MetaTags (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Image (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Image src CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT title (brand, name)>
<!ELEMENT brand (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Specs (CPU, GPU, RAM, Storage, OS, optional)>
<!ELEMENT CPU (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT GPU (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT RAM (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Storage (HDD | SSD)>
<!ELEMENT HDD (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT SDD (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT OS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT optional (Monitor | Keyboard | Mouse)*>
<!ELEMENT Monitor (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Keyboard (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Mouse (#PCDATA)>
```

**XML**

```
<entry id='c01'>
    <MetaTags>Business</MetaTags>   
    <title><brand>HP Pavilion</brand><name>550-112NA</name></title>
    <Description>While other towers have been standing still, HP has revolutionized the category. From magnified performance and reliability, to its stylish redesign, this HP Pavilion is the best thing to happen to towers in over 20 years.</Description>
    <Price>€579</Price>
    <Image src="Image1.jpg"/>
    <Specs>
        <CPU>A10-8750 APU</CPU>
        <GPU>Radeon R7</GPU>
        <RAM>8 GB DDR3</RAM>
        <Storage><HDD> 2TB </HDD></Storage>
        <OS>Windows 10</OS>
        <optional>
            <Monitor>LG 22" Full HD TV</Monitor>
            <Keyboard>Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600</Keyboard>
            <Mouse>Logitech M705 Mouse</Mouse>              
        </optional>
    </Specs>
</entry>
```